# How to set a maxLength of NUMBER input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Sounds trivial, but it doesn't work for me... I tried to set a max length of **NUMBER** input, but it doesn't work. 
Your help is appreciated. Here's my code. Both don't work in Chrome

```
<input id="demo02" type="number">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#demo02").attr('maxlength','2');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#demo02").prop('maxlength','2');
});
```

Comment: You cannot set `maxlength` for inputs of type `number`.

Comment: `maxlength` does not work on number inputs, only text, email, search, password, tel, or url https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`maxlength` is not a valid attribute for `input type="number"`.

With this in mind, we will use the valid `max` attribute to get its value length and use it as a maxlength within an `input` event listener.

We will target the `input` elements of type `number` that have a `max` attribute set:

`$('input[type=number][max]:not([max=""])')`

Code Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type=number][max]:not([max=""])').on('input', function(ev) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var maxlength = $this.attr('max').length;
    var value = $this.val();
    if (value && value.length >= maxlength) {
      $this.val(value.substr(0, maxlength));
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" max="99999">
```

Comment: might consider using `input` event. Can still paste invalid entries in

Comment: @Ricky What if I have more than one Number inputs in my code? will they all be set to 'maxlength' 5 or they will be set to 'maxlength' for every isolated input?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, had to change the validation since preventing the default behavior with `input` event will still change the input value.

Comment: @Ricky I just tried it and it works perfect! There is only one problem - If I enter the number using the up-arrows of the number input I can enter a number bigger than the limit. For example I can enter 10 by limit 9. Is there a solution?

Comment: @Ricky I just tried it. In chrome it goes just higher - from 999 to 1000 an so on. In the Snippet works just I told you

Comment: @Pussyfer I edited my answer, please check that it works as you expect.

Comment: should be `var maxlength = $this.attr('max');` without the `.length` is suffice

Answer (score 0):

Use [`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Specifying_minimum_and_maximum_values) attribute to limit the highest available number. If you set `max` to `99`, you can't go any higher.

```
$("#demo02").attr('max','99');
```

Or with plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('demo02').setAttribute('max', 99);
```

```js
document.getElementById('demo02').setAttribute('max', 99);
```

```html
<input id="demo02" type="number">
```

Comment: @Pussyfer it works from validation standpoint. Won't prevent you exceeding it though

Comment: @charlietfl I add it in my code, both of them and I can still enter like 100 numbers in a roll...

Comment: @Pussyfer that's right. Never found number input very developer friendly. You have to use input event to modify it if it exceeds the max. But it will be invalid in html5 validation

Comment: @charlietfl I don't get it - if I enter the number using the arrows of the input it works fine (I can't enter a value greater than 2), but if i type i can type like zillion characters... Is there a problem Would you help me with input event code?

Comment: Personally I just don't use number input. No idea why browser vendors made them allow what you describe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162133/discussion-between-pussyfer-and-charlietfl).